# Replace grouped elements of a list

Tags: r

I have a column in a data.frame with repeated elements like:

> ```
>  7     
>  7    
>  7     
>  7     
>  7   
>  b
>  b
>  b        
>  c
>  c
>  c
>  c
>  c
> ```

I don't know which are the elements that are repeated because the data.frame is the result of previous calculations. For example: the repeated elements could be 3 as in this case (i.e. 7,b,c) or 4 in other cases or 2 and so on and they also could be different (i.e. 4,a,f, or 10, s, 3). I would like to replace the repeated elements with a list of colours. For example, in this case:

> ```
>  blue     
>  blue    
>  blue     
>  blue     
>  blue   
>  yellow
>  yellow
>  yellow        
>  red
>  red
>  red
>  red
>  red
> ```

Or if the list is composed only by two repeated groups, the elements of the groups will be assigned to blue and yellow respectively. Is this possible? 
I'm able to replace elements of a list but not when I don't know how many groups are in the data.frame without to print it and table it.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use factors:

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('7','7','7','7','7','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c'),stringsAsFactors = F)
repl<- c("blue","yellow","red","purple")
```

**solution**

```
df$col1 <- factor(df$col1)
levels(df$col1) <- repl
df$col1 <- as.character(df$col1) # optional, if you want character and not factor
df
#      col1
# 1    blue
# 2    blue
# 3    blue
# 4    blue
# 5    blue
# 6  yellow
# 7  yellow
# 8  yellow
# 9     red
# 10    red
# 11    red
# 12    red
# 13    red
```

Comment: the simplest and more robust!

Comment: Wow!Exactly what I need! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
# 1. create the data frame with the column
df <- data.frame(mycol = c(rep("7",5), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 5)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# stringsAsFactors = FALSE makes the strings not to convert to Factor type
# one of the super annoying default behaviour of base-r

df

   mycol
1      7
2      7
3      7
4      7
5      7
6      b
7      b
8      b
9      c
10     c
11     c
12     c
13     c


# 2. create a translation vector
colors <- c("7" = 'blue', "b" = "yellow", "c" = "red")
# or like this: colors <- c("blue", "yellow", "red")
# and then    : names(colors) <- c("7", "b", "c")

# 3. replace the column value according to translation vector
df$mycol <- colors[df$mycol]
# this is cool in R: The vectorization - no for loops or such needed in this case
# use the vectorization!

df
    mycol
1    blue
2    blue
3    blue
4    blue
5    blue
6  yellow
7  yellow
8  yellow
9     red
10    red
11    red
12    red
13    red
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I need. I don't to print the df and manually set colors <- c("7" = 'blue', "b" = "yellow", "c" = "red") because the piece of code will be in a pipeline. I would like that it recognises the replicated and replaces it with color code.

Comment: But in the comment below this line I showed you how to do it in another way - to not to have to do  `colors <- c("7" = 'blue', "b" = "yellow", "c" = "red")`. And it recognizes the replicates automatically - is just it looks incredibly simple - because of the vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may help your need.

```
 recode(x, "'7'='blue'; 'b'='yellow'; 'c'='red'")
```

Comment: Not exactly since I don't know every time which are the repeated elements.

Comment: So you don't know the codename for the color from the previous table?

Comment: then you can do one checkup before that and use `unique(x)` function to find out, how many groups there are, and based on the result, assign the values with recode.

Comment: Okkk Daglina. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One can use both `dplyr` package and `data.table::rleid` function together to get a solution which will work with `dplyr-chain`.

Suppose the color vector of preference that should contain maximum number of possible color occurrence is:

```
myColor = c("blue", "yellow", "red", "black", "pink")
```

Otherwise once even use `colors(distinct = TRUE)` instead of `myColor`.

**Option#1:** A solution can be achieved as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>% mutate(Color = myColor[rleid(Col)])

#OR -- If someone doesnt want to use `data.table` then solution can be as
df %>% mutate(Color = myColor[cumsum(Col != lag(Col, default = ""))])

#    Col  Color
# 1    7   blue
# 2    7   blue
# 3    7   blue
# 4    7   blue
# 5    7   blue
# 6    b yellow
# 7    b yellow
# 8    b yellow
# 9    c    red
# 10   c    red
# 11   c    red
# 12   c    red
# 13   c    red
```

**Option#2:** Using `colors(distinct = TRUE)`

```
df %>% mutate(Color = colors(distinct = TRUE)[cumsum(Col != lag(Col, default = ""))])
#    Col        Color
# 1    7        white
# 2    7        white
# 3    7        white
# 4    7        white
# 5    7        white
# 6    b    aliceblue
# 7    b    aliceblue
# 8    b    aliceblue
# 9    c antiquewhite
# 10   c antiquewhite
# 11   c antiquewhite
# 12   c antiquewhite
# 13   c antiquewhite
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Col                   
7     
7    
7     
7     
7   
b
b
b        
c
c
c
c
c",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```